# Why does Console2 return the cursor at weird offsets?

Tags: terminal, powershell, console2

Here is a screenshot where I type "quit" repeatedly within ghci:

[image]

This behavior occurs when using both PowerShell and cmd.exe. The settings for "Don't wrap long lines" and "Trim trailing spaces" don't seem to affect this at all. Resizing the window does nothing.

I know that the proper way to quit ghci is `:quit`, but I'm deliberately mistyping it here to show this weird offset issue.

Comment: You need to report the bug to ghci author.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug with ghci because I've seen this behavior with other programs before.

Comment: BTW, you may try ConEmu. It may behave better with DBCS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I manually opened PowerShell and cmd.exe outside of Console2 to test this, I noticed that my fonts were a bit weird. That's when I remembered that I had set the language for non-Unicode programs to be Japanese. I switched the language back to English, which fixed this issue.

The language can be changed at Control Panel > Clock, Language, and Region > Region and Language > Administrative > Language for non-Unicode programs > Change system locale